# OCCI linkage: Undefined symbols

Tags: c++, oracle, solaris, sparc, occi

I have been working in a solution with Oracle database access and C/C++.
I'm using OCCI but we are in trouble to link in Solaris 11.
Solution works "like a charm" in Linux (OpenSUSE and Mint), but doesn't in Solaris 11.

Here environment informations:

1. I downloaded instantclient_11_2 (sun sparc version) and unpacked it in a Solaris folder
2. I created symbolic links to libclntsh.so.11.1 called libclntsh.so, and for libocci.so.11.1 called libocci.so. Bellow a "ls -l" showing files:

   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv     23792 Aug 22  2013 adrci
   - -rw-rw-r--   1 f780333  desenv       414 Aug 22  2013 BASIC_README
   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv     41464 Aug 22  2013 genezi
   - lrwxrwxrwx   1 f780333  desenv        17 Apr  5 14:21 **libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1**
   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv   50268448 Aug 22  2013 **libclntsh.so.11.1**
   - -r-xr-xr-x   1 f780333  desenv   8653320 Aug 22  2013 libnnz11.so
   - lrwxrwxrwx   1 f780333  desenv        15 Apr  5 14:22 **libocci.so ->   libocci.so.11.1**
   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv   1545008 Aug 22  2013 **libocci.so.11.1**
   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv   118735824 Aug 22  2013 libociei.so
   - -r-xr-xr-x   1 f780333  desenv    121800 Aug 22  2013 libocijdbc11.so
   - -r--r--r--   1 f780333  desenv   2091135 Aug 22  2013 ojdbc5.jar
   - -r--r--r--   1 f780333  desenv   2739616 Aug 22  2013 ojdbc6.jar
   - drwxrwxr-x   4 f780333  desenv         7 Aug 22  2013 sdk
   - -rwxrwxr-x   1 f780333  desenv    177680 Aug 22  2013 uidrvci
   - -rw-rw-r--   1 f780333  desenv     66779 Aug 22  2013 xstreams.jar
3. I created another folder that contens symbolic links to important needs libraries from Solaris.I am linking project with options -m64 -lCstd -lrt -lsocket. m64 to force 64bits, it was necessary. Cstd, rt and socket due the fact that these libraries are used indirectly.
4. I am using Netbeans and compile remotely in Solaris 11

Compilation works fine.
Compilation command patterns is showed bellow:

g++ -m64   -c -g -I/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/indra_clib/include -I/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include -std=c++98 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/main.o main.cpp

**/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/indra_clib/include** is a folder with a static library used by program. This library is mine and is necessary for project.

**/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include** is a folder from instantclient sdk, that includes *.h from OCCI.

But when linkage process starts, all head pain starts too:

(first) Linkage command:

```
g++ -o <all files here> -L/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/sun -L/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib -L/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/instantclient_11_2 -R'/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/sun' -R'/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib' -R'/home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/instantclient_11_2' -lclntsh -locci /home/f780333/paineldaemon/lib/libindra_clib.a -m64 -lCstd -lrt -lsocket
```

And finally the linker **ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
Undefined           first referenced
  symbol                in file
oracle::occi::Date::~Date()         build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Date::Date()          build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Number::operator=(oracle::occi::Number const&) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Number::Number(double) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilder.o
oracle::occi::Number::Number(long)  build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilder.o
oracle::occi::Number::Number()      build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Number::~Number()     build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::Mode, void*, void* (*)(void*, unsigned long), void* (*)(void*, void*, unsigned long), void (*)(void*, void*)) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/DatabaseOperation.o
oracle::occi::Date::operator=(oracle::occi::Date const&) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilderATM.o
oracle::occi::Environment::terminateEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment*) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/DatabaseOperation.o
oracle::occi::Date::Date(oracle::occi::Environment const*, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) build/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/MessageBuilder.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Solaris-Sparc/paineldaemon] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/home/f780333/.netbeans/remote/172.16.160.172/sylvia-Linux-x86_64/home/eduardo/Indra/Cartoes/repo/paineldaemon'
gmake[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/f780333/.netbeans/remote/172.16.160.172/sylvia-Linux-x86_64/home/eduardo/Indra/Cartoes/repo/paineldaemon'
gmake: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I am crazy with this problem, any help will be much apreciate.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, OCCI has always been built for Solaris by using the Solaris Studio compiler.

You can't *link* an executable that uses `CC`-built code using `g++`, unless you can somehow coerce `g++` to link in both the C++ run time libraries `libCrun.so` and `libCstd.so` along with the proper C++ run-time startup code, the same as Solaris Studio's `CC` does.  That's probably not impossible, but it would be easier to just invoke `ld` directly and link the binary yourself.

And you can't *compile* C++ source code with `g++` to match the name-mangling scheme used by Solaris Studio `CC`.  (unless the code was built with a later version of `CC` *and* it used command-line arguments to produce `g++`-compatible name-mangling, among many other compatibility requirements, which in my experience `OCCI` never has been...)

In short, you need to use Solaris Studio's `CC` compiler to use OCCI on Solaris.